# Known problems in BQP \ NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, np, quantum-computing

The introduction to Nielsen and Chuang has an Euler diagram of the suspected relationships between various complexity classes which shows $\text{BQP}$ extending slightly outside of $\text{NP}$. Is $\text{BQP} \not\subset \text{NP}$?  Are there any specific problems known or suspected to be in $\text{BQP}$ but outside of $\text{NP}$? If so, what's the simplest known example?

Comment: No. ​ ​ ​ ​ BQP $\subseteq$ [AWPP](https://cse.sc.edu/~fenner/papers/awpp.pdf#page=3) ​ is [known to hold](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/9811023v1.pdf#page=6), but ​ [P-unifor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_complexity#Polynomial-time_uniform)m [AC$^0$\[6\]](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:A#ac0m) ​ is not known to differ from [PP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#pp). ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Then why do we believe that NP does not contain BQP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there was a problem known to be in $\text{BQP}$ but not $\text{NP}$, that would prove $\text{BQP} \not\subset \text{P}$. But $\text{BQP}$ vs $\text P$ is *also* still an open problem.

It is *suspected* that $\text{BQP} \not\subset \text{NP}$. In fact [it's suspected that $\text{BQP} \not\subset \text{PH}$](http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/bqpph.pdf) via the "Recursive Fourier Sampling" problem. But proving separations between complexity classes is surprisingly hard. I don't think anyone's even managed to show that $\text{BQP} \not\subset$ [$\text{LSPACE}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_%28complexity%29).

Comment: [related](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/56803/12859) ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I'm not certain enough of my "I don't think" to put it as an answer to that question.